# How to append pipe character in a comma delimited string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a SSIS package which is pulling data from a SQL database and generating a comma delimited flat file. The flat file is to be used to import the data into a system and it is causing issues with the text field values in the file as it contains comma in the value.

I am now told to insert the pipe character | as the text qualifier for all text fields.

Example
`1234,Smith, John,5678` should be `1234,|Smith, John|,5678`

I followed the tutorial in this [link](http://www.techbrothersit.com/2016/04/how-to-export-all-tables-to-flat-files.html) to create my SSIS package for the export. It is using a Script Task with the Visual C# script pasted below, which I finding it difficult on how to modify to prepend and append the pipe character to the text values consisting the comma character.

I think it is this part where I will need to insert the pipe character, but I do not know the C# language enough to modify it as needed. Any help or reference resource would be really helpful and appreciated.

> 

```
                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                        if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                        
                    }
```

> 

```
        string datetime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");
        try
        {

            //Declare Variables
  string DestinationFolder = Dts.Variables["User::DestinationFolder"].Value.ToString();
  string FileDelimiter = Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();
  string FileExtension = Dts.Variables["User::FileExtension"].Value.ToString();
           


            //USE ADO.NET Connection from SSIS Package to get data from table
            SqlConnection myADONETConnection = new SqlConnection();
            myADONETConnection = (SqlConnection)(Dts.Connections["DBConn"].AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction) as SqlConnection);


            //Read list of Tables with Schema from Database
          string query = "SELECT Schema_name(schema_id) AS SchemaName,name AS TableName FROM   sys.tables WHERE  is_ms_shipped = 0";

            //MessageBox.Show(query.ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, myADONETConnection);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            
            //Loop through datatable(dt) that has schema and table names
       foreach (DataRow dt_row in dt.Rows)
            {
                string SchemaName = "";
                string TableName = "";
                object[] array = dt_row.ItemArray;
                SchemaName = array[0].ToString();
                TableName = array[1].ToString();
               
               string FileFullPath =DestinationFolder +"\\"+ SchemaName+"_"+TableName + "_" + datetime+FileExtension;

            //Get the data for a table into data table 
            string data_query = "Select * From ["+SchemaName+"].["+TableName+"]";
            SqlCommand data_cmd = new SqlCommand(data_query, myADONETConnection);
            DataTable d_table = new DataTable();
            d_table.Load(data_cmd.ExecuteReader());
     
                    StreamWriter sw = null;
                    sw = new StreamWriter(FileFullPath, false);

                    // Write the Header Row to File
                    int ColumnCount = d_table.Columns.Count;
                    for (int ic = 0; ic < ColumnCount; ic++)
                    {
                        sw.Write(d_table.Columns[ic]);
                        if (ic < ColumnCount - 1)
                        {
                            sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                        }
                    }
                    sw.Write(sw.NewLine);

                    // Write All Rows to the File
                    foreach (DataRow dr in d_table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (int ir = 0; ir < ColumnCount; ir++)
                        {
                            if (!Convert.IsDBNull(dr[ir]))
                            {
                                sw.Write(dr[ir].ToString());
                            }
                            if (ir < ColumnCount - 1)
                            {
                                sw.Write(FileDelimiter);
                            }
                        }
                        sw.Write(sw.NewLine);
                        
                    }
                    
                    sw.Close();                            
              
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
            }

        }

        catch (Exception exception)
        {

            // Create Log File for Errors
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Dts.Variables["User::LogFolder"].Value.ToString() + "\\" +
                "ErrorLog_" + datetime + ".log"))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(exception.ToString());
                Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;


            }
        }
```

Comment: `sw.Write(FileDelimiter);` Is this not the specific code that adds your delimiter? In turn, that string variable is set with `string FileDelimiter =  Dts.Variables["User::FileDelimiter"].Value.ToString();`. That is a package variable - discussed in the first step in your link. Somehow I doubt you want both comma and pipe as a field delimiter - but only you can know that.

Comment: You only want the pipes if a comma is in the field. this is c# for that....
field.Contains(",") ? "|" + field + "|" : field

Answer (score 0):

Is the package somewhat hard-code query written for getting data and what will be made available for the export process?  If so, is the data ONLY for export process from the query?  Or is it query data, show some report, then allow the export to comma separated list from same results?

I know, bunch of questions.  But if your query is exclusively to pull the data for export, why not tack on the pipes as you query the data, something like

```
select
      SomeIntegerColumn,
      '|' + SomeStringField + '|' as SomeStringField,
      '|' + AnotherString + '|' as AnotherString
      SomeDateColumn,
      etc
   from
      ...
```

Then the data is already formatted for you ready to go.

Comment: There are several Views from which the package is pulling the data and exporting a flat file for each of those Views. I thought of modifying the Views with the pipe character, but then was wondering if there is another better way.